# How to Empty a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

In my app i have a WindowsForm called "Dashboard.cs" within that it has a TableLayoutPanel called `dashboardTableItemsWrapper`.
Now once a user click on the refresh button it will empty the table, in order to do that here is code which will be triggered once the click event will be occurs.

```
dashboardTableItemsWrapper.RowStyles.Clear();
dashboardTableItemsWrapper.ColumnStyles.Clear();
```

But this way the refresh button is not working, instead it will append new data in the table row, but i want to empty the table first and then append new data to it.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the TableLayoutPanel as a type of excel-ish view to some data?

Comment: Please add the [tag:winforms] tag to Windows Forms questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear(v=vs.80).aspx) tells me `Controls.Clear` removes the controls from the parent control, but doesn't remove them from memory, causing a memory leak. Editing to add safe disposal.

```
for (int i = dashboardTableItemsWrapper.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
     dashboardTableItemsWrapper[i].Dispose();

dashboardTableItemsWrapper.Controls.Clear(); 
dashboardTableItemsWrapper.RowCount = 0;
```

Comment: And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) is a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but there is a really easy way to fix this.

```
while (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count > 0)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[0].Dispose();
}
```

The problem with other approaches is that as soon as you delete one control from the list of Controls, the next one will be modified and the loop will not work correctly. With this approach you can just keep removing the first element while there are still elements in the list.

Comment: thats the reason the loop is going from end to beginning in the other answer (by @RaGe). you mustve tried to loop from beginning to end, which will not work. both approaches achieve the same result, two sides of the same coin. the other answer also removes the actual cells in the table, which your code does not do.